# How to add a month to a specific date with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, date

I use `now()` function to obtain a date. I tried to add a month with many functions like:

```
$today= date("Y-m-d");
$date1 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($today, ' + 1 month'));
```

and after load `$date1` to MySQL DB, but when I see in DB the date inserted is `0000-00-00`.
How can I add this month?

Answer (score 1):

You made this more complicated than it needs to be.

```
$date1 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(' + 1 month'));
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/1004615)

`strtotime()` will assume "now" if you do not pass it a date and time.

Otherwise, the way you called it, you should be seeing this error:

> Warning: strtotime() expects parameter 2 to be integer, string given in /tmp/execpad-a8173d5d91cb/source-a8173d5d91cb on line

This is because `strtotime()` expects the second parameter to be a Unix timestamp and you clearly provide a string. The closet approximation to your code would be

```
$today= time();
$date1 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(' + 1 month', $today));
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/1004621)

If the date is still going into the database incorrectly then you have an issue outside of your date code.

Answer (score 0):

Having a date in MySQL turn up as `0000-00-00 00:00:00` usually indicates that the date you tried to store in the database did not have a valid format / was not recognized as date by MySQL. Maybe it is a problem with the way you insert or update the date value?

You can also directly add a month to a date in MySQL without the need to do the calculation in PHP by using the builtin function [DATE_ADD()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) of MySQL:

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH);
```

For example, the query

```
SELECT DATE_ADD('2018-05-15 12:34:56', INTERVAL 1 MONTH);
```

will return the result:

```
+---------------------------------------------------+
| DATE_ADD('2018-05-15 12:34:56', INTERVAL 1 MONTH) |
+---------------------------------------------------+
| 2018-06-15 12:34:56                               |
+---------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Using that you could also directly update a date value to a date that is one month ahead:

```
UPDATE table_name SET column_name = DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
WHERE id = your_id;
```

(Replace *table_name*, *column_name*, *id* and *your_id* according to your needs.)